# Adobe DTM Path Condition for Homepage

Tags: regex, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I could make up a regular expression to target just the homepage, but is there anything built into Adobe DTM to target the homepage only?

Answer (score 3):

No, DTM does not offer a built-in definition/rule for "Homepage". "Homepage" is an abstract/arbitrary concept that can mean different things to different people/sites. For example, there are plenty of sites whose "home page" and all public facing pages have some kind of dir path prefix (common for /country/lang/ setups).  So, you define what "home page" means to you via the conditions, just as you thought to do :)